# How to use TokenDayData in Uniswap

Tags: api, cryptography, token, uniswap

I am using uniswap v2 subgraph to get data. [TokenDayData](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/API/entities#tokendaydata) lets you search historically. I'm trying to [query historical data](https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2?selected=playground) for a token with this query:

```
{
  tokenDayData(id: "0x56143e2736c1b7f8a7d8c74707777850b46ac9af-19086.058842592593") {
    token {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

and getting the response:

```
  "data": {
    "tokenDayData": null
  }
```

How can I get real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just trying this myself and got this to work:

```
{
  tokenDayDatas(
      where: {
        token: "0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984",
        date_gt: 1661717376
      }, 
      orderBy: date, 
      orderDirection: asc) {
    date
    token {
      id
      symbol
    }
    volumeUSD,
    untrackedVolumeUSD,
    priceUSD,
    open,
    high,
    low,
    close
  }
}
```

some of the examples here helped: https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/subgraph/subgraph-examples

looks like you're using "tokenDayData" (which is what I used initially), but notice the working query uses "tokenDayDatas" (which is odd, but whatever)